# I want to post data to this website via android,but how to get the behind interface url

Tags: android, post

It is the URL for register:https://hkclubs.samsung.com/seca/mobile/#/home/member_register/0

I want to write a application for register.
I know how to handle POST on locathost, php, mysql, but I dont know how to use on world wide web0

Who can teach me.Please

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.15:8080/user_register.php");
            try {

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                        HTTP.UTF_8);

                httppost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String responseBody = EntityUtils
                        .toString(response.getEntity());

                    return false;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

I catch the ids using developer tool

```
main_form_login_email
main_form_login_password
confirmPassword
first_name
last_name
_year
_month
_date
phone
radio_gender_m
```

Comment: hey man, what is the issue? What happen if you replace the URL with the server ?

Comment: @Karoly how to get the url for post? It is not the directly URL

Comment: the developer tool show the post url is: https://hkclubs.samsung.com/api/registration/register       It is not a php

Comment: but is the php behind it ?

Comment: @Karoly I dont know how to get the behind interface url :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you replace 
http://192.168.1.15:8080/user_register.php
with
https://hkclubs.samsung.com/api/registration/register ?
I think they are the same backend! Is it works ?